# Mysql multiple column index using wrong index

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have indexes on **products** table:

1. PRIMARY
2. products_gender_id_foreign
3. products_subcategory_id_foreign
4. idx_products_cat_subcat_gender_used  *(multiple column index)*

QUERY:

```
select `id`, `name`, `price`, `images`, `used`
from `products`
where `category_id` = '1' and
      `subcategory_id` = '2' and
      `gender_id` = '1' and
      `used` = '0'
order by `created_at` desc
limit 24 offset 0
```

**Question:**

Why mysql uses index

> products_subcategory_id_foreign

insted of

> idx_products_cat_subcat_gender_used (multiple column index)

HERE IS EXPLAIN :

> 1 SIMPLE  products    NULL    ref products_gender_id_foreign,products_subcategory_id...   products_subcategory_id_foreign 5   const   2   2.50    Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort

Comment: You seem to have a very small number of rows, so the specific index doesn't really matter.

Comment: Any [tag:query-optimization] question should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>`

Comment: while hard to read your index names, `created_at` potentially could be added to the end of the index. Try not to quote number if the fields are numberic.

Comment: You need to add an index to `created_at` to possibly avoid `filesort`.

Comment: Please, no handwaving; provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see exactly what indexes you have, plus datatypes, and other things.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz - Adding `created_at` will _not_ avoid filesort _unless_ the index also handles _all_ of the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html), a index can be ignored in some circunstances. The ones that could apply in your case, as one index is already beeing used, are:

- You are comparing indexed columns with constant values and MySQL has
  calculated (based on the index tree) that the constants cover too
  large a part of the table and that a table scan would be faster. See
  Section 8.2.1.1, “WHERE Clause Optimization”.
- You are using a key with low cardinality (many rows match the key
  value) through another column. In this case, MySQL assumes that by
  using the key it probably will do many key lookups and that a table
  scan would be faster.

My guess is that the values of category_id are not sparse enough

Answer (score 1):

As I say [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql), this

```
where `category_id` = '1' and
      `subcategory_id` = '2' and
      `gender_id` = '1' and
      `used` = '0'
order by `created_at` desc
limit 24 offset 0
```

needs a 5-column composite index:

```
INDEX(category_id, subcategory_id, gender_id, used,  -- in any order
      created_at)
```

to get to the `LIMIT`, thereby not having to fetch lots of rows and sort them.

As for your actual question about which index it picked...  Probably the cardinality of one inadequate index was better than the other.